# How do you convert a String to Object in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I'm making a dependent dropdown column in Google Sheets that has a bunch of different things of a type. I've named the ranges I want to use and I've got column A with those names in the dropdown. The problem is, I can't use the contents of column A to reference in column B's data verification.

E.g. I select Tech in column A, column B reads that as "Tech" when I want it to be able to reference the named range Tech. How to you convert from the string "Tech" to the named range Tech? Is there a way without using a stupidly long nested IF on every single row of B column's data verification?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you try INDIRECT it?

Comment: @player0 That is exactly what I need yeah. The issue is I want a drop down menu but it won't accept any formulae in the input box for the range. So I'd need a new Indirect for every single row that I want the dependent dropdown in which was what I was trying to avoid
Edit: which means I'd basically have a whole new sheet for the sole purpose of providing explicit ranges using the INDIRECT function which is pure insanity.

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?